# Como separar a logica da interface em consultas com mongodb e nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

estou estudando o Mongodb e o NodeJs, estou iniciando . Baixei um codigo de exemplo do git e comecei a personalizar. O codigo original da consulta era assim:

```
router.get('/products/:page', (req, res, next) => {
                 
   let perPage = 9;
   let page = req.params.page || 1;

   Product
     .find({}) // finding all documents
     .skip((perPage * page) - perPage) // in the first page the value of the skip is 0
     .limit(perPage) // output just 9 items
     .exec((err, products) => {
       Product.count((err, count) => { // count to calculate the number of pages
         if (err) return next(err);
         res.render('products/products', {
           products,
           current: page,
           pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
         });
       });
     });
});
```

Porem preciso separar a logica da consulta do router, entao criei este fonte:

```
const Product = require('../produto/product');


exports.ListaProdutos = async (req, res, next) => {
        let perPage = 9;
        let page = req.params.page || 1;
      
        await Product
          .find({}) // finding all documents
          .skip((perPage * page) - perPage) // in the first page the value of the skip is 0
          .limit(perPage) // output just 9 items
          .exec((err, products) => {
            Product.count((err, count) => { // count to calculate the number of pages
              if (err) {
                  return next(err)}
              else {
                 res.render('products/products', {
                 products,
                 current: page,
                 pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
               })
            };
            });
          });
};
```

E o meu router alterei par este codigo:

router.get('/products/:page', (req, res, next) => {
ProdutoDAL.ListaProdutos(req, res, next);

});

Continua funcionando perfeitamente. Porem se notarem dentro do método Listaprodutos ainda respondo a consulta com um res.render('products/products'.
Eu não gostaria que ficasse assim. Eu gostaria que o método Listaprodutos retornasse apenas os dados
e o router apenas testasse se o retorno tem dados e executasse o res.render.

Como faço isto?
Eu tentei :

```
if (err) {
   return next(err)}
else {
   return products;
     };
```

Mas desta forma não sei como tratar o retorno da função no router.
E tem outro agravante que eh a paginação que o código original implementa. Como vou passar para o router as variáveis: perpage  e page?

Outra pergunta: Está certo o que estou tentando implementar?

Enfim, estou mais perdido que cego em tiroteio. Preciso aprender, mas quero aprender do jeito certo.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, o código exemplo que você pegou no Git foi implementado de forma didática, para fácil entendimento. Por isso, tudo é feito no mesmo arquivo e no mesmo bloco de código. Mas em uma aplicação em produção as coisas não são feitas assim. Em desenvolvimento web por exemplo, geralmente segue-se algum padrão de desenvolvimento, como o [MVC](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-padrao-mvc/29308) (Model, View, Controller). A Model contém o escopo de classe dos objetos que sua aplicação manipula, o controller engloba todos os métodos que manipulam esses objetos das models e a view é o que é retornado para o usuário.

Você disse que queria que o router ficasse separado da consulta. Essa consulta é nada mais que o controller dessa model Products que você criou. O router é um roteamento apenas, ele não deve executar nenhuma tarefa além de apenas referenciar o controller de acordo com a url acessada. Portanto, é responsabilidade do controller fazer a consulta e retornar os dados, no caso com a res.render. Ainda sobre padrão de desenvolvimento as rotas também podem possuir um padrão como por exemplo o [REST](https://rockcontent.com/br/blog/rest-api/).

Por último, recomendo estudar um pouco sobre arquitetura de software web. Isso vai mostrar um pouco sobre o padrão MVC e a divisão do código na aplicação para fácil entendimento de qualquer desenvolvedor que venha a entrar no projeto.

Comment: Esta parte eu entendi, mas o que preciso saber e: Se onde eu declaro a rotinaexports.ListaProdutos eu posso usar res.render ou isso deveria ficar no router?